# Jquery on android not working well

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

In this code, javascript not work!

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///app/assets/", String.format(htmlText, post.getContent()), "text/html", "utf-8", "");

String str = "";
str = "<script src='file:///app/assets/couraselcss.css' type='text/javascript'></script>" +
"<script src='file:///app/assets/jquery-2.1.0.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>" +
"<script src='file:///app/assets/jquery.touchcarousel-1.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>" +
"<script type='text/javascript'>" +
```

in the folder "assents" there are 3 files (jquery + css).
Javascript is not working properly!!!

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I found that jQuery 2.1.0 won't work for me either in the Android browser but downgrading to jQuery 1.11.0 gets things working as expected.

If you don't need any special jQuery 2.x features, this'll probably work for you too.